# Mark Jenkins Job chain as failed if any downstream job fails

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, phabricator

I have a set of chained freestyle jenkins jobs which we use as a build pipeline for several projects, we recently integrated it with our source repository management (phabricator) so it reports the continuous integration build result back to the merge request (whether if it failed or passed).

Due to some limitations with Phabricator, the way we are triggering the pipeline is through an AWS lambda function which knows what's the first job of the chain and starts it, since it's all chained together, triggering the first job executes the whole pipeline.

The issue is, technically we are triggering a single job (which triggers a downstream job as well and so on), so, if the first job passes, it will return a green build to Phabricator no matter if the second job fails, it won't wait for any of the downstream projects to finish, if the first one passed, it will say it build is green.

As I see it, there are two questions that come to my mind to solve this:

1.- Is there a way to mark the job as failed if the downstream project fails?
2.- Is there a way to trigger the chain instead of a single job? that way I think it will return the result of the chain instead of the single first job.

Any thoughts and advice are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered rewriting your Jenkins chain as a single [pipeline job](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/)?  I think this would make your life a lot easier.
Otherwise, you need to pass the Phabricator build ID down through your chain, and only post back a success response in the final job, with a fail response from any job that fails.

Comment: Yes, the thing is we are moving away from Jenkinsfiles, we are using a YAML based contract to define the pipelines and generate the jobs directly on Jenkins